# C Malloc 3D array

Tags: c

I am trying to run the code below, but I receive an error (during the **for** loop). It seems that my "3D array" is defined (for i, j, k max) as **c[nL_thread][nL][nL]** while I am trying to set the indices as **c[nL][nL][nL_thread]**, hence the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<mpi.h>

double ***alloc3(int x, int y, int z){

    int i, j;
    double *p = (double *) malloc(x*y*z*sizeof(double));
    double ***array = (double ***) malloc(x*sizeof(double **));

    for (i=0; i<x; i++){
        array[i] = (double **) malloc(y*sizeof(double *));
        for (j=0; j<y; j++){
            int idx = x*j + x*y*i;
            array[i][j] = &p[idx];}}

    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int i, j, k;
    int nL;
    int nL_thread;

    double ***c;
    int nbr, rank;

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nbr);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    nL = 10;
    nL_thread = 4;

    c = alloc3(nL+1, nL+1, nL_thread+1);

    for(k=0; k<=nL_thread; k++){
        for(j=0; j<=nL; j++){
            for(i=0; i<=nL; i++){
                c[i][j][k] = 0;}}}

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Note: `x*y*z` in `x*y*z*sizeof(double)`  can overflow `int` math.  `sizeof(double)*x*y*z` has the advantage of using `size_t` math, certainly wider than `int`.  Important if your x,y,z values are large.

Comment: "I receive an error (during the for loop)" --> Please describe the error indication and provide any error message.

Comment: `int idx = x*j + x*y*i;` should be `int idx = z*j + y*z*i;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your allocation function. The calculation of the offset `idx` is wrong:

```
int idx = x*j + x*y*i;
```

should be

```
int idx = z*j + y*z*i;
```

Note that `array[i][j+1]` should point to `z` elements after `array[i][j]`, and `array[i+1][j]` should point to `y*z` elements after `array[i][j]`. That is the reason why the sizes seem switched (but maybe also leads to out of bounds access).